# How can i add margine at top and bottom of pdf page in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, jspdf, html2canvas

Providing code snippet of generating pdf file.
Im trying to get an table converted into Pdf. To do that im using html2canvas and creating image of that table.
Image is getting inside of the pdf but im not getting any image break at the end of pdf page. Need space ta bottom and top of each page.
I also need to add a title at the top of each page.

```
html2canvas($("#LogBookReport"), {

    onrendered: function (canvas) {

        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var imgWidth = 200;
        var pageHeight = 290;
        var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        var heightLeft = imgHeight;
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm','a4');
        var position = 40;
             
        doc.addImage($scope.PdfPrintData.img,'PNG',5,3,20,20);// adding logo on first page  
        doc.setFontSize(15);
        doc.text(80, 15, 'Teaching Log - Report ');// page titile
        doc.setFontSize(9);
        doc.text(10, 25, 'Branch Name: ');//static data
        doc.setFontSize(9);
        doc.text(150, 25, 'Date: ' );//static data
        doc.setFontSize(9);
        doc.text(10, 30, 'Teacher Name: ');//static data
                       
        doc.setFontSize(9);
        doc.text(10, 35, 'Downloded By: ');//static data
        doc.setFontSize(9);
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 5, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);// adding table image
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;

        while (heightLeft >= 0) {
            doc.addPage();
            position = heightLeft - imgHeight+40;
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG',5, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            heightLeft -= pageHeight;
        }
        if (confirm("Are you sure do you want to download this file ")) {
            filename = " LogBook Report "+'.pdf';
            doc.save(filename);
        }

    }
});
```